# How to round decimal places in swift 2

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, decimal, rounding

Trying to output the total of three number values from a dictionary and then adding HST of 13% to the total. However, the calculations print out as **$13.5261** with four decimals places. How do I cut out the end decimal places, so it's $13.52? Or is there a way to round it, so it's $13.53

```
import UIKit 


 var menu = ["Coke": 1.99, "Coffee": 3.99, "Water": 5.99]

 var hst = 1.13

 var total = hst * (menu["Coke"]! + menu["Coffee"]! + menu["Water"]!)


 print("The total for your order is
 $\(total)")
```

Comment: Don't round, use formatting

Comment: Yes, use formatting, but you may need to rounding as well, if you'll be doing any further arithmetic with this number.

Comment: @Rob If you are doing any arithmetics with money, you should use `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's my point. It's not just as simple as just "use formatting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual – and most versatile – way is `NSNumberFormatter`

```
let menu = ["Coke": 1.99, "Coffee": 3.99, "Water": 5.99]

let hst = 1.13

let total = hst * (menu["Coke"]! + menu["Coffee"]! + menu["Water"]!)

let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()   
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
let roundedTotal = formatter.stringFromNumber(total)!

print("The total for your order is $\(roundedTotal)")
```

Answer (score 3):

To format a floating point number, rounded to a certain number of digits, use `NSNumberFormatter` as discussed by others.

To actually round the numbers (rather than just displaying it using a certain number of decimal places), you can use `Decimal`:

```
let menu = ["Coke": 1.99, "Coffee": 3.99, "Water": 5.99]
let hst = 1.13

let subtotal = menu
    .map { Decimal($0.value).round(2) } // convert the values to decimals
    .reduce(Decimal(0), +)              // add them up

let rate = Decimal(hst).round(2)        // get rate as decimal
let total = subtotal * rate             // calculate total
let result = (subtotal * rate).round(2) // round it
```

Generally, just using `NSNumberFormatter` is adequate, but if you're going to do any subsequent arithmetic with these rounded numbers (e.g. add up a bunch of rounded numbers), you actually have to round them, like shown above, rather than relying on the formatter.

FWIW, here is the rounding routine used above:

```
extension Decimal {
    func round(_ scale: Int, roundingMode: NSDecimalNumber.RoundingMode = .plain) -> Decimal {
        var value = self
        var result = Decimal()
        NSDecimalRound(&result, &value, scale, roundingMode)
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't round, use formatting:

```
let total: Double = 13.5261
let currency = "USD"

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.currencyCode = currency

print("The total for your order is \(formatter.string(from: total as NSNumber)!)")
```

This will print the money amount correctly in all locales and with the currency symbol positioned correctly.

You don't have to care about the number of decimal digits with `.currency` because it will use the number of decimal digits that should be used with money values.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Darwin
let d0 = 1.12345654
let r0 = round(d0)                          // 1
let r1 = round(10 * d0) / 10                // 1.1
let r2 = round(100 * d0) / 100              // 1.12
//...
let r7 = round(10000000 * d0) / 10000000    // 1.1234565
```